# How to commonly use not operator for two queries in ODATAV4?

Tags: odata, odata-v4, not-operator

Currently, my query string is like below,

```
http://localhost:49442/Orders/?$count=true&$filter=not%20(Freight%20eq%202.3)%20and%20(startswith(tolower(CustomerID),%27b%27))&$skip=0&$top=12
```

But here not-operator only worked to filter the **Freight** column. But I want to commonly us this not-operator to filter **Freight** and **CustomerID**.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to identify your intended expression as it is half-way between two:

1. If you want to exclude only the rows where both of the following are true at the same time:

   - Freight eq 2.3
   - Customer starts with 'b'

   Then you can do this by rearranging the brackets, the following is the same as saying:
   *"Exclude orders where the Customer starts with b, but **only if** the freight is 2.3"*

   ```
   http://localhost:49442/Orders/?$count=true&$filter=not(Freight eq 2.3 and startswith(tolower(CustomerID),'b'))&$skip=0&$top=12
   ```
2. If instead you want to exclude all orders that have customers that start with 'b' **AND** also exclude all other orders where the freight is 2.3 then you must specify *not* twice in your query

   - This is the same as: *"Exclude orders where the Customer starts with b, **or** if the freight is 2.3"*

     ```
     http://localhost:49442/Orders/?$count=true&$filter=not(Freight eq 2.3) and not(startswith(tolower(CustomerID),'b'))&$skip=0&$top=12
     ```

Comment: @Kural did this help or did you solve this in another way?